# Hints on feature selection for vectorial features

Tags: feature-selection, feature-engineering

##### My actual question:

Everything I've seen on feature selection excluding wrapper methods focuses on scalar features. I would like to ask for hints or sources that focus on non-wrapper methods of vectorial feature selection, as I haven't been able to find them on my own.

##### My particular problem (for context):

I have two datasets $[A,y]$ and $[B,y]$, where $A$ and $B$ are sets of input features and $y$ is the output variable of a classification problem. Let's say that $A$ is composed of 5 scalar features per sample and $B$ is composed of 7. I want to evaluate which of these pieces of data $A$ or $B$ performs best in the task of predicting $y$ without using [wrapper methods](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2020/10/a-comprehensive-guide-to-feature-selection-using-wrapper-methods-in-python/). This resembles a feature selection problem with two features in which each is a vector of 5 and 7 elements, respectively.

I've been looking into mutual information to approach this problem. So far when computing the MI (with [this implementationn from sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.mutual_info_classif.html)) for, let's say $A$, I get a vector of mutual informations that allows me to compare features in $A$ and see which ones are most correlated to the output $y$. However I do not understand this well enough to know how to extend this so I can compare features of $A$ and $B$ as a whole.

```
>>> from sklearn.feature_selection import mutual_info_classif
>>> 
>>>
>>> ## A and B are two-feature data where each row is a sample
>>>
>>> A
array([[-0.07134442, -1.21050869],
       ...,
       [-0.51325213,  0.82609899]])
>>> B
array([[ 1.85091202, -3.0069708 ],
       ...,
       [-0.25981791, -0.41778624]])
>>>
>>> 
>>> ## Mutual informations of each dataset with output variable Y
>>>
>>> mutual_info_classif(A, Y)
array([3.37253569e-02, 4.03705059e-05])
>>>
>>> mi_b = mutual_info_classif(B, Y)
array([0.01085871, 0.02290524])
```

Comment: Let’s do an example. You want to predict someone’s salary. Your features in A are their years of education and years of experience. Your features in B are their month of birth and whether they liked the movie *Pulp Fiction*. How would you evaluate which set of features is more predictive of salary?

Comment: @Dave Using mutual information I could know, for instance, that years of experience is more relevant than years of education and that month of birth is more relevant than _Pulp Fiction_. However, I can't do cross-comparisons with my knowledge. Take the much more ambiguous case where the pairs are {years of education, month of birth} & {years of experience, liked _Pulp Fiction_}, which pair would be more effective? Allow me a minute to add some code with some example matrices.

Comment: Which of those sets of predictors do you think will give the model with better estimates of salary? I would expect the former.

Comment: @Dave From the set {years of education, month of birth} & {years of experience, liked _Pulp Fiction_} I do not know. From the ones you initially proposed, logic says its going to be A. However, I wouldn't be able to known for certain without running a wrapper method (which I want to avoid) in any of these cases.

Comment: Why not just fit the models and see which performs better?

Comment: @Dave Research. Fitting many different models worrying about hyperparameters, deeper data transformations etc might end up taking a lot of time. I am interested in approaching a faster and generalistic way of foreseeing whether one dataset is less ambiguous than other, if that's even possible.